# C++ How to pass array to a print function?

Tags: c++, arrays

The program asks the user for a number of random numbers,
then gives a menu of what to do with the arrays.
I want to print the arrays to the standard output device.

How do I pass "baseArray[i]" and "copyArray[i]" to "arrayPrint(int arr[], int size)" ?

```
void randN() {
    int n;
    cout << "Enter a number (in the set of integers) of random numbers to generate. (e .g 1000)\n> ";
    cin >> n;

    int baseArray[n], copyArray[n];

    time_t nTime;
    srand((unsigned) time(&nTime));
    cout << "Random numbers between 0 to 1000\n" << endl;
    for (int i = n; i != 0; i--){
        baseArray[i] = rand()%1000 + i;
        copyArray[i] = baseArray[i];
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
    pMenu();
}

void pMenu(){
    int selectioN = 0;
    cout << "Main Menu\n";
    cout << "1 - Generate Random Array\n";
    cout << "2 - Print The Original Array\n";
    cout << "3 - Print The Copy Array\n";
    cout << "4 - Exit program\n" << endl;
    cout << "Selection >> ";
    cin >> selectioN;
    switch (selectioN) {
        case 1:
            randN();
            break;
        case 2:
            arrayPrint(baseArray, 1000);
            break;
        case 3:
            arrayPrint(copyArray, 1000);
            break;
        case 4:
            pExit();
            break;

    }
}

void arrayPrint(int arr[], int size){
    for (int i = 1000; i != 0; i--){
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

I tried to make separate functions for menu, arrayPrint, and the random number generator.

I tried to call the function in the menu to print each array.

When I build, I get the error that baseArray and copyArray are not declared in this scope, which I understand the meaning of that already, but how do I declare them, do I need to dereference the arrays?.

Comment: 1) forget that C-style arrays exist in the language. 2) use `std::array` or `std::vector`.

Comment: Please note that `int baseArray[n], copyArray[n];` is *not* standard C++ when `n` is not a constant expression. If you need a container based on runtime sizing, `std::vector` should be the go-to option.

Comment: `srand((unsigned) time(&nTime));` - that's a really poor seed - for a really poor random number generator. Take a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random . Also; *don't* seed the generator multiple times (every time the function is called) - seed it *once*.

Comment: `baseArray[i] = rand()%1000 + i;` - this is biasing your random numbers. Look up the "pigeon hole principle". You are better off using a `std::uniform_int_distribution`.

Comment: The variables are local to your `randN()` function, they are not defined in `pMenu()` function and can therefore not be passed to `arrayPrint( ... )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the local array variables into global variables.

I also updated the random number generator based off of this:
[std::uniform_int_distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).